# Couldn't template<typename> deduce pointer type?

Tags: multithreading, templates, c++11, promise, future

I have the following program, compile+run, no problem

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
void f(int* first,
       int* last,
       std::promise<int> accumulate_promise)
{
    int sum = std::accumulate(first, last, 0);
    accumulate_promise.set_value(sum);  // Notify future
}

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::promise<int> accumulate_promise;
    std::future<int> accumulate_future = accumulate_promise.get_future();
    std::thread work_thread(f, begin(numbers), end(numbers),
                            std::move(accumulate_promise));
    accumulate_future.wait();  // wait for result
    std::cout << "result=" << accumulate_future.get() << '\n';
    work_thread.join();  // wait for thread completion
}
```

But if I change "f" into a template:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void f(Iterator first,
       Iterator last,
       std::promise<int> accumulate_promise)
{
    int sum = std::accumulate(first, last, 0);
    accumulate_promise.set_value(sum);  // Notify future
}
```

Then it fails compilation，gcc report that thread::thread() ctor cannot find proper overload:
error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(, int*, int*, std::remove_reference&>::type)'

What is the message indicating, anything wrong with my template?
How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` is a template.

```
std::thread work_thread(f, begin(numbers), end(numbers),
                        std::move(accumulate_promise));
```

To put it in loose terms, `std::thread`'s first parameter is either a function pointer or something that acts like a function pointer. It doesn't take a template as the first parameter.

A template becomes a class, or a function, when it is instantiated. The template gets instantiated when it gets used. So, given this template definition, and using it in a manner like this:

```
f(something.begin(), something.end(), some_kind_of_a_promise);
```

this instantiates a template, and uses it. To instantiate a template explicitly, without using it:

```
f<int *>
```

Now, you have an instantiated template here. The following works here:

```
std::thread work_thread(f<int *>, std::begin(numbers),
                        std::end(numbers),
                        std::move(accumulate_promise));
```

Tested with gcc 5.3.1